# Why in the symfony 5.3 in prod mod I get a 503 error while in dev mod not

Tags: symfony, production-environment, production, symfony5

I have a symfony 5.3 project that has no problems in dev mod but as soon as I get the project to prod mode I get a 503 error.
The method is as follows

```
    public function index($username,$lesson = 'lesson1'): Response
    {
        if (!$this->getUser()) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_login');
        }
        $student = $this->studentRepository
        ->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->andWhere('s.isArchive = :is_archive')
        ->setParameter('is_archive', false)
        ->andWhere('s.username = :username')
        ->setParameter('username', $username)
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
        if(!$this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')){
            if ($this->getUser()->getUsername() != $student->getAdviser()->getUsername()) {
                return $this->redirectToRoute('app_login');
            }
        }
        $azemoon_ha = $this->azemoonRepository
        ->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->andWhere('a.student = :student')
        ->setParameter('student', $student)
        ->andWhere('a.isArchive = :is_archive')
        ->setParameter('is_archive', false)
        ->orderBy('a.id', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
        $azemoon_arr = [];
        $azemoon_arr['meta']['lesson1'] = null;
        $i = 1;
        if(is_null($azemoon_ha)){
            // dd($azemoon_ha);
            foreach ($azemoon_ha as $value) {
                $az_metas = $value->getAzemoonMetas();
                // dd($az_metas);
                $c_num = 1;
                $keys = [];
                foreach ($az_metas as $am) {
                    $azemoon_arr['meta']['lesson'.$c_num][] = $am->getVal();
                    $keys['lesson'.$c_num] = $am->getName();
                    $c_num++;
                }
                $azemoon_arr['name'][]     = 'آزمون '.$i;
                $azemoon_arr['tarazKol'][] = $value->getTarazKol();
                $azemoon_arr['tarazOmomi'][] = $value->getTarazOmomi();
                $azemoon_arr['tarazEkhtesasi'][] = $value->getTarazEkhtesasi();
                $i++;
            }
        }else{
            $this->addFlash('error', 'برای دانش آموز '.$student->getName().' ازمونی تعریف نشده است');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('student.info', ['username'=> $username]);
        }
        // dd($azemoon_arr['meta'], $keys);
        return $this->render('dars_status/index.html.twig', [
            'student' => $student,
            'azemoon_arr' => $azemoon_arr,
            'az_meta'     => $azemoon_arr['meta'],
            'keys'        => $keys,
            'lesson'      => $lesson
        ]);
    }
```

According to my review, the error occurs from the moment the $ azemoon_ha variable is created
Where do you think the problem is?

Comment: Interestingly, when I clear the prod cache from the var / cache path, the page loads at the same time. And if the page is reloaded again, a 503 error will be received. pls help me

Answer (score 5):

I solved my problem. I share, maybe it will work for you too
The main problem with my app was caching some data
I used the following code and did not allow them to be cached
First I created a file called config.yaml in the path config / packages / prod and entered the following code in it

```
framework:
    cache:
        app: cache.adapter.null
        system: cache.adapter.null

services:
    cache.adapter.null:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\NullAdapter
        arguments: [~] # small trick to avoid arguments errors on compile-time.
```

Comment: thank you very match. it saved my day

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain a bit more

Comment: I ran into the same problem with pages throwing an 503 error after being loaded for the second time. The suggestion above solves the problem. But I wonder if it is a good solution or just some dirty workaround as I never had to apply that config on other projects.